# Issues with @ElementCollection In Hibernate 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When using @ElementCollection with Set = SetOf() I get org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Only support for basic-valued, entity-valued and embedded model-parts have been implemented : NewName  [PluralAttribute]

This worked before upgrading to hibernate 6